# Does external $B$-field affects cross-sections at colliders?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, large-hadron-collider

The answer is yes **https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04322**
this is article related to QFT computations, but what is important here is that the cross-sections for various diagrams DO! depend on external magnetic field (which was a surprize for me)

If so, I wonder if this effect have been treated properly before to compare QED results with experiments? Because as I know, cross-sections must be strictly coinsident with the theory. But I have never seen computations like that before...

Even an electric train bypassing the collider facility can cause deviations in equipment working (that was the case with LEP collider, when physicists had to reevaluate the $Z_0$ resonance width)

Comment: There are no values of B  in tesla to see if the magneitc fields in the interaction regions of the experiments are strong enough to show an effect, even for these unphysical particles.

Comment: the electric field example, as also the earth tides, are irrelevant except in defining the macroscopic measurement errors.  You are talking about quantum states.

Comment: Notice that the magnetic fields considered in this paper are about 15 orders of magnitude larger than even those provided by the LHC's superconducting magnets.

Comment: the paper you quote is talking of B fields created during *interactions* in heavy ion collisions, https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.1396 ,at the LHC, not of ambient magnetic fields.

Comment: I was not thinking about this before, but in some cases (like e+e- collider) magnetic field could be extremely strong! This is due to so-called pinch effect which reduces the effective beam size and leads to an increase in luminosity.  And so it means that cross sections are machine dependent lol (because then the current value also affects them)

Comment: And also I didn't understand the correlation to earth tides...@annav